# Green caterpillars pest on kale, what to do after finding and removing the pests?

Tags: pests, pest-damage, kale

I had recently discovered and removed what appears to be [Cabbage loopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbage_looper) on some of my kale, as shown in the images below.
What is the best decontamination procedure after removal? Should I give the plants a thorough rinse and transplant it with some fresh potting soil?

[image: Cabbage looper on kale plant]
[image: Cabbage looper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caterpillar that you have there is from the white moth. They are all over my garden. I literally harvested some lettuce + arugula today and made a salad and found about 5-6 of those caterpillars on the leaves. I rinsed the leaves with water best I could and enjoyed the salad.

I wouldn't over think it. I'm sure I've probably missed a few in my life and actually eaten some of those caterpillars. To reduce the number of caterpillars spray a neem oil solution on the leaves especially the underside of your leaves.

Answer (score 2):

No point washing the plant or changing potting mix. You could look on the leaves and remove the eggs weekly (most likely on the underside of the leaves).

Answer (score 2):

These are probably cabbage loopers. You can use the biological control [*Bacillus Thuringiensis*](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/pesticides/using-bacillus-thuringiensis.htm), commonly known as BT. It is a bacteria that infects many caterpillars, causing them to stop eating and they starve to death. It is non-toxic to humans.